# Neo4J Cypher - How to perform IN clause operations on a list of lists

Tags: neo4j, cypher

In Neo4J, for a simple IN clause check, one can simply do e.g.:

itemList = [i1,i2,i3]

- item IN itemsList

but how to perform an IN operation on list of lists, e.g.

- itemList1 = [i1,i2,i3], itemList2=[i4, i5, i2], itemList3 =[i1,i7,i8]
- itemLists = [itemList1, itemList2, itemList3]
- item IN itemLists

I need to use the operation in conjunction with CASE WHEN, e.g.

CASE WHEN i1 IN itemLists THEN true

Comment: you can also use `IN apoc.coll.flatten(nestedList)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `any()` and `all()` list predicates for this, depending on what you need.

So to check if a value is in any of the lists present you can use:

```
any(list in itemLists WHERE i1 IN list)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `case / when / in` solution works, but you can also try to flatten your array and then used the `in`.

Example : `x in reduce(s = [], list IN itemLists | s + list)`

Comment: Thanks. This also worked, but I went with the answer from InverseFalcon.

Answer (score 0):

You could just add the lists togerther if you want.

```
WITH 'i1' AS tester 
, ['i1','i2','i3'] AS list1
, ['i4','i5','i6'] AS list2
, ['i7','i8','i9'] AS list3
RETURN CASE 
  WHEN tester IN (list1 + list2 + list3) THEN true
  ELSE false
END AS in_list
```

Comment: Answers from InverseFalcon and logisma were more in line with what I needed, but thanks nevertheless